# Paypal subscription Plan: Trial Payment Definition + Cycles parameter

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm wondering one thing about TRIAL payment definition in Paypal's billing plans.

In the API documentation the "Create Billing plan" example is quite straightforward.. but I can't get one detail to wrap in my mind:

```
"payment_definitions": [
    {
        "name": "Regular payment definition",
        "type": "REGULAR",
        "frequency": "MONTH",
        "frequency_interval": "2",
        "amount":
        {
            "value": "100",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "cycles": "12",
        "charge_models": [
            ....
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Trial payment definition",
        "type": "trial",
        "frequency": "week",
        "frequency_interval": "5",
        "amount": {
            "value": "9.19",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "cycles": "2",
        "charge_models": [
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

The trial payment definition reads as:

Trial is 9.19 each 5 weeks.. for two cycles.. So, **question 1**: it's 10 weeks trial for a total of 18.38? Right?

I want to simplify this to make this API compatible with other APIs (MercadoPago and Stripe) and they only allow certain amount of free trial days... cannot charge for the trial part... So: I want to simplify paypal's trial definition to this same model.

Free trial for X days only (not months, weeks or whatever)... Lets say 60 days trial for this case. This is the payment definition I came up with:

```
{
    "name": "Trial payment definition",
    "type": "trial",
    "frequency": "day",
    "frequency_interval": "60", //this should change depending on the amount of free days
    "amount": {
        "value": "0",
         "currency": "USD"
    },
    "cycles": "1"
}
```

**Question N° 2**: is this payment definition correct for my setup?

Thank you guys!

Comment: `$paymentDefinitionTial = new PaymentDefinition();
$paymentDefinitionTial
                    ->setName($nombre . ' (trial)')
                    ->setType('TRIAL')
                    ->setFrequency('Day')
                    ->setCycles(1)
                    ->setAmount(new Currency(['value' => 0, 'currency' => $currency]))
                    ->setFrequencyInterval($trial);

$plan->addPaymentDefinition($paymentDefinitionTial);`

This was my free trial implementation.. but I ended up using start_date because I needed to be able to change the plan without restarting the trial